# Setup Alert when SQL Agent Down using Task Scheduler

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking something to setup alert notification when SQL agent is down, sometimes when windows patch apply or server get rebooted SQL Agent is not restarting even though we have set up SQL Agent properties Auto Restart SQL Server if it stops unexpectedly

Auto Restart SQL Server Agent if it stops unexpectedly.

I have also tried to setup services on Component service on server to at Recovery tab, First Failure Restart the service and also restarted service rebooted but didn't work.

Is it any way I can get the alert so I can restart service manually when it's Agent is down it it will trigger to restart the job when Agent it's down.

Answer (score 1):

```
$AgentStatus = (Get-Service -ComputerName <CompName> -Name <SqlServerAgentName> | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Stopped"} | Measure-Object).Count

If($AgentStatus -eq 1){
Start-Service -Name SqlServerAgentName

$SMPTPort = <Specify port number>

$From = "email1@domain.com"
$To = "email2@domain.com"

$Subject = "The SQL Server Agent Service in $env:ComputerName has been restarted."
$Body = "The SQL Server Agent Service <SqlServerAgentName> was in a Stopped state and has been restarted."

$SMTPServer = "SMTP SERVER"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, $SMPTPort)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $false
$SMTPClient.Send($From, $To, $Subject, $Body)}
```

Comment: Thanks Israel. So if i create the PowerShell script using this code then how can i call this script automatically?

Comment: 1. Save the code into a text file (after modifying); 2) Change the file extension to .ps1 as CheckSqlAgentServiceStatus.ps1 and put it into a a directory (e.g., PowerShell_files) in the drive you like to keep it (e.g., C:\). The file path will be like C:\PowerShell_files\CheckSqlAgentServiceStatus.ps1; 3) Create a task scheduler to execute the PowerShell. The following links will guide you on how to create a task scheduler https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38580.configure-to-run-a-powershell-script-into-task-scheduler.aspx

Comment: Thanks once again Israel. But this was i have to setup schedule timing for everyday to run it, right? Actually i am looking when service stops then it's run automatically not everyday as it's happens very rare.

Comment: Look at this link how to use Windows Event to setup a triggering event (Event ID 102 for SQL Server Agent stopped) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/

Comment: Please re-word your answer with some comments and explanation, as to why it should be an acceptable answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a batch file below which checks for service status. This sends an SMTP mail (using powershell) along with restarting service again.

for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "MyServiceName" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer SMTPSERVER -To someone@domain.com  -From noreply@domain.com  -Subject Testing -Body Service_Not_Running

net start "MyServiceName"
  )
)

Once you have the script ready, create a task scheduler to call the batch file. Run the scheduler every 1 hr or so.

Comment: Thank you very much. I prefer to run automatically like any windows event happens (Ex. Server stop or service stops) then it's triggers and send notifications.